# How to create svn repository with series folder before

Tags: svn

How can I create an svn repository that looks like this?  I want the series folder before.

```
/var/www/
  ▾ svn/
    ▾ android/
      ▾ project1 
        ▾ trunk
        ▾ branches
        ▾ tags
```

Answer (score 0):

`cd /var/www/svn`

`svnadmin create android`

This will create an empty repository. Checkout the repository and create the folder structure as you want. Use `svn add` to add these folders and then `svn commit`.

You can use `svn mkdir -m "some comment" http://repourl/android/project1` also to create folders.